# Custom condition throws error 'The code produced is invalid'

Tags: personalization, cdp, sitecore-personalize

I have created a custom condition in `Personalize` that checks whether the current date and time is after a target date and time specified in UTC timezone (see full code below). When I test the condition, it gives the expected result. I have published the condition and am trying to use it in XM Cloud.

However, when configuring the audience in `Sitecore Pages`, I'm getting the following error:

```
Your audience was not saved. The code produced is invalid. 
To fix the problem, please contact our support team.
```

When checking the network tab, I can see that the PUT call to [https://api-eu-west-1-production.boxever.com/v3/flowDefinitions/[id]](https://api-eu-west-1-production.boxever.com/v3/flowDefinitions/%5Bid%5D) returns a 400 (Bad Request) with the same error details.

I have tried to create a web experience in Personalize and use the custom condition there, and that goes without issues. Has anyone encountered this before and has an idea what's causing the error?

```
(function () {
    load("classpath:moment.js");
    load("classpath:moment-timezone.js");
    var returnValue = false;
    var comparison = false;
    var comparator = "[[is | enum(is, is not) | is | { required: true }]]";
    var operatorValue = "[[compares to | enum(is greater than,is less than) | | { required: true, placeholder: compares to} ]]";
    var inputDateTime = `[[DateTime | string | | {required: true, max: 14, placeholder: YYYYMMDDTHHmmZ}]]`
    var currentDateTime = moment().utc();
    var targetDateTime = moment.utc(inputDateTime);
    if (operatorValue === 'is greater than') {
        comparison = currentDateTime > targetDateTime;
    } else if (operatorValue === 'is less than') {
        comparison = currentDateTime < targetDateTime;
    }
    if (comparator === "is") {
        returnValue = comparison;
    } else {
        returnValue = !comparison;
    }
    return returnValue;
})();
```

Comment: Did you contact support?